# How to use fonts in Magento from fonts-family installed in theme/fonts?

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, local.xml, fonts, font-family

I added the code line below in local.xml with link to google, but we do not want to rely on an external url.

```
    <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>stylesheet</rel><href>//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans</href></action>
```

So, we installed the "Open Sans" fonts-family (10 fonts) in skin/frontend/default/(our theme)/fonts.
What are the code lines we must add in local.xml to call multiple fonts from our local theme?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add font in xml

Go to your style add below code in your stylesheet

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Open+Sans;
    src: url(../fonts/Open+Sans.ttf);  
}
```

Comment: We tried that previously and it didn't work (it crashed the whole style sheet). I will try again with your solution. Thanks Prashant